# Python3 request - Post request with Form Data

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm trying to send a POST Request with form data to some form. I'm using *requests* package.

```
#!/bin/python3.6
import requests

FFF_search = 'https://www.fff.fr/la-vie-des-clubs/resultats'
data = {'address':75000}
session = requests.session()
r = session.post(FFF_search, data=data, headers={'User-Agent':'test'})
print(r.text)
```

This gives me the result page where no result is found.

Maybe my problem is more about the data I'm sending. 
Here's the POST request as it must be done on the website (Chrome dev tools).

[image: POST request]

Answer (score 0):

You should consider several issues:

- Your's `headers` dict is not valid. There is no 'User-Agnet' that called test. You should use only valid headers [headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). Try to send all the headers you see in the network tab.
- Your's data us clearly wrong. You should send the described Form Data ad a dictionary and pass it with `data=data`, as you do (but you do it with a wrong data). Maybe the data you are passing now is the `params`?

Try to send the exact request like your's browser sending (with the same params and headers), and see the results you are receiving, with paying attention to the issues above.